# newline in bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, script, newlines

My script contains something like this:

```
ifc=$(ifconfig)
```

With this, the `ifc` variable contains the output of the command `ifconfig` but without newlines. So, when I print it with `echo $ifc` I get only one line.

How can I include the newlines of subcommands?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct way to print is

```
echo "$ifc"
```

Comment: Works!  Why, though?

Comment: see *Word Splitting* in `bash(1)`, you need quoting to preserve the spaces, tabs, or newlines.

Comment: Short answer: For example if you excute this on the shell:
`myecho  arg1        arg2`
Your program `myecho` will never receive those spaces between arg1 and arg2.   Your program only get `arg1` in your `argv[1]`, and `arg2` in your `argv[2]`.  The whites (spaces, tabs, newlines) are not preserved. (`argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are the 1st and the 2nd arguments for your program `myecho`)  If you quote it (i.e. `myecho "arg1        arg2"`), then the whole quoted text are now your `argv[1]`, incluing those spaces.